# Can S3 be used for GitLab Advanced Search (Elastic Search) indexing?

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-s3, gitlab, nas, san

I am using GitLab 16.0.8-ee and working on enabling Advanced Search with Elastic Search. I would like to know whether S3 storage is supported to store, accumulate the index and pull the data during search? Or should I use NAS/SAN storage for Elastic Search indexing?

I have installed GitLab on VMs cluster. Can I have the Elastic Search cluster configured on containers with S3 and integrate it with GitLab for Advanced Search? Or should I need to configure the Elastic Search cluster on VMs?

Appreciate your inputs!